# Cannot Resolve Symbol R -existing solutions aren't working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having issues solving the above error when creating my app in android studio.I have tried various solutions such as Build-Clean project, Build-Rebuild project, re-started android studio, File-Invalidate Caches which doesn't help.Could anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Is the SDK properly installed ? What shows up when you go to tools -> Android -> SDK manager ?

Comment: It shows that an update is available